# Andengine - Object pool or generic pool optimisation

Tags: android, object, sprite, andengine, objectpool

I am creating a game which generates many sprites at some point such as bullets.
I am using object pooling which is generic pool in andengine.
But the problem I am facing is it lags when the object are created for the first time. As for the first time , when the object is attached to scene. It lags when I am attaching 100 sprites at a time.

So I was thinking if its possible to load all the required objects and load it to the pool while in loading scene.

for now my code is as follows..

```
bullets = bullet_pool.obtainPoolItem();

if(!bullets.hasParent())
    {
    Presentscene.attachChild(bullets);
    }
```

Please suggest me some ideas.

Can I load a 100 objects (sprite) in the pool before the game, So that It wont lag in the middle of the game to create objects fresh for the pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-load the amount of bullets you want during the loading sequence of the game. Something like this:

```
private void preloadBullets(){
    Bullet[] bulletArr = new Bullet[1000];
    // Create the new bullets
    for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i){
        bulletArr[i] = bullet_pool.obtainPoolItem();
    }
    // Recycle all bullets
    for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i){
        bullet_pool.recyclePoolItem(bulletArr[i]);
    }
}
```

This way, if you call `preloadBullets` before your game runs, you'll have 1,000 bullets recycled in the pool for fast item obtaining.